# gulp: concat, uglify and inline JavaScript - sourcemaps not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm working on a AngularJS application and using gulp for the build-process. I have multiple JavaScript files (for controllers, services, directives, etc.) which I concat, uglify and then inline into an `index.html` in order to minimize the amount of server connections.

Here comes the problem:

- When I *do not* inline the concatenated and uglified JavaScript files into `index.html`, the sourcemaps work when I debug the application with the developer tools.
- When I *do* inline the JavaScript files into `index.html`, then my breakpoints are never hit. Why? I'm not sure, what I'm doing wrong.

This is the relevant part of my [gulpfile](https://github.com/PzYon/KeyPearl/blob/master/Client/gulpfile.js):

```
// isPublish is set to true to uglify.
// the temp-folders are here just for testing purposes, I tried with
// and without and I have also changed the order of the gulp-command.
return gulp.src(definition.srcs)
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(replace("$build:serverApiBaseUrl$", args.serverApiBaseUrl || "..."))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(targetFolder + "/temp1"))
           .pipe(concat(definition.targetFile))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(targetFolder + "/temp2"))
           .pipe(gulpif(isPublish, uglify()))
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(targetFolder));
```

Please see [here](https://github.com/PzYon/KeyPearl/tree/master/Client) for the whole solution, e.g. for the project structure, etc. Even though I think this isn't really of any relevance for my problem.

Another thing I realized is that even though the breakpoints get hit (when *not* using the "inlined"-mode), the variable names are still in the mangled format (i.e. only letters). Is this a expected browser behavior (i.e. do developer tools not support this?), or do I need to specify something special for the `sourcemaps`-command? I don't understand why, as the generated sourcemaps contain the `names`-information.

**Update I (13.10.2015)**

I realized I could also use following method:

```
return gulp.src(paths.target + "index.html")
           .pipe(inline({
                base: paths.target,
                js: uglify()
           }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target));
```

This however doesn't seem to work due to a [issue](https://github.com/ashaffer/gulp-inline/issues/14) in `gulp-inline`. There seems to be a [pull request](https://github.com/ashaffer/gulp-inline/pull/31), no idea when it will be merged back though. And even if it would work, I'm not sure what will happen with the sourcemaps in that case..?

**Update II (19.10.2015)**

Version `0.1.0` of `gulp-inline` has been released today (see pull request mentioned in "Update 1" which has now been merged back). It now works correctly with `gulp-uglify`, i.e. the bug has been fixed. I still couldn't get the sourcemaps to work though. Not sure if this is supported by `gulp-inline`.

So for the time being, I'm still searching for a solution..